# User searching for items in an array

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently trying to build an app that will allow a user to choose a position in an array and then have that selection displayed back to the user after they've selected they're position in the array. My Code so far is. (in C#)

// String Array

```
    string[] nameArray = new string[] { "Tyler", "Kyle", "Roger", "Rick" };

    Console.WriteLine("Select an item from the array using numbers 0-3");
    string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
    int arraySelection1 = Convert.ToInt32(userSelection);
    Console.WriteLine("You have choosen " + arraySelection1);
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("You have choosen " + arraySelection1[userSelection]);

Answer (score 0):

Just get the element from an `array` by its `index` (note that index is zero based):

```
Console.WriteLine($"You have choosen {nameArray[arraySelection1]}");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not a search, it is a direct array access — by the element index. For this purpose, please, consider using the [[] Operator (C# Reference) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index-operator).

Additionally, please, note:

> Arrays are zero indexed: an array with `n` elements is indexed from `0` to `n-1`.
>
> — [Arrays (C# Programming Guide) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

So, please, consider adding the appropriate check.

Here is the example:

```
string[] nameArray = new string[] { "Tyler", "Kyle", "Roger", "Rick" };

// Input.
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Select an item from the array using numbers {0}-{1}", 0, nameArray.Length));
string selectedIndexString = Console.ReadLine();

// Processing.
int selectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(selectedIndexString);
if (selectedIndex < 0 || selectedIndex >= nameArray.Length)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The index must belong to the range: [{0}:{1}]", 0, nameArray.Length));
}
string selectedString = nameArray[selectedIndex];

// Output.
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("You have choosen: {0}", selectedString));
```